# how to playing audio in background mode when If i click on iphone button to "minimize" the app?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I'm work on new iphone audio application.

When i open the app, the Audio was loaded and started. If i click on iphone button to "minimize" the app, the sound was stopped. I need the sound still playing in background mode.

How i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play in the background, add an Array  entry named "UIBackgroundModes" your .plist file, and add "audio" as array member.

.plist entry:

```
UIBackgroundModes Array
Item0 String audio
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at AVAudioSession also.

```
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];
```

That should help.