# IOS: Play sound while app in background

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I working on a little app where i want the phone to play a sound file on an event from my location controller.
The problem is when the App is in Background mode the AVAudioPlayer not start the Audio file but the code is scheduled, getting NSLog output.
Another thing is it works in the simulator but not on the phone.

Whys not?

This is my code to play the file:

```
- (void)tryPlayTaleSound:(NSString*)fileName {

    NSString *backgroundMusicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *backgroundMusicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:backgroundMusicPath];
    NSError *error;

    backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];

    // Check to see if iPod music is already playing
    //UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(otherMusicIsPlaying);
    //AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, &propertySize, &otherMusicIsPlaying);

    // Play the music if no other music is playing and we aren't playing already
    //if (otherMusicIsPlaying != 1 && !backgroundMusicPlaying) {
    //[backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    backgroundMusicPlaying = YES;
    //}
    NSLog(@"%s - ", __FUNCTION__);
}
```

In the log Im getting this.

```
Apr 26 13:57:48 iPhone CommCenter[58] <Notice>: Client [com.apple.persistentconnection[dataaccessd,85]] is telling PDP context 0 to go active.
Apr 26 13:57:50 iPhone Herning100[1467] <Warning>: Playing audiofile - filename is Fil03
Apr 26 13:57:50 iPhone mediaserverd[39] <Warning>: 13:57:50.653 <AudioControl> WARNING translating CMSession error: -12985 
Apr 26 13:57:50 iPhone mediaserverd[39] <Warning>: 13:57:50.656 <AudioControl> WARNING translating CMSession error: -12985 
Apr 26 13:57:50 IPhone mediaserverd[39] <Error>: 13:57:50.734 <AudioControl> AudioQueue: Error -12985 from AudioSessionSetClientPlayState(1467)
Apr 26 13:57:50 iPhone Herning100[1467] <Warning>: -[AppDelegate tryPlayTaleSound:] - 
Apr 26 13:57:50 iPhone com.apple.debugserver-199[1465] <Warning>: 9 +28.832083 sec [05b9/0303]: error: ::mach_vm_region_recurse ( task = 0x1603, address => 0xfffffffe, size => 0, nesting_depth => 1024, info => 0x2fd7fe48, infoCnt => 12) addr = 0xfffffffe  err = (os/kern) invalid address (0x00000001)
Apr 26 13:57:51 iPhone com.apple.debugserver-199[1465] <Warning>: 10 +0.187961 sec [05b9/0303]: error: ::mach_vm_region_recurse ( task = 0x1603, address => 0xfffffffe, size => 0, nesting_depth => 1024, info => 0x2fd7fe48, infoCnt => 12) addr = 0xfffffffe  err = (os/kern) invalid address (0x00000001)
```

Is there a difference if I use the AVAudioPlayer or the AVAudioSession.?

Hope someone can help.

/Lasse

Comment: I hope this link may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785925/how-to-playing-audio-in-background-mode-when-if-i-click-on-iphone-button-to-min

Answer (score 12):

In addition to having background mode `audio` in your `Info.plist` you need to set the shared audio session to the correct mode for your app and activate it just before playing your sound in the background:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *error = nil;
NSLog(@"Activating audio session");
if (![audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to set audio session category: %@", error);
}
BOOL result = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
if (!result) {
    NSLog(@"Error activating audio session: %@", error);
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Don't forget to deactivate the audio session when you are done playing sounds:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *error = nil;
NSLog(@"Deactivating audio session");
BOOL result = [audioSession setActive:NO error:&error];
if (!result) {
    NSLog(@"Error deactivating audio session: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: OP: I am doing the exact same thing as you and this solution worked perfectly. I have some other code that I added this to, so if this doesn't work for you let me know and I can share what I did to make it work ontop of what glebd already wrote.

Comment: thanks, I need to set the category to "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback" to play audio is when app is in background.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting playing a sound in the background, set up a background task. It seems that iOS refuses to start a sound in the background if the remaining background time is less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS only some of the applications are allowed to run in background. One of them is Audio player application but for them you need to set "required background modes" with "audio" (App can play audio) in your Info.plist.

And Yes if you are able to get Location in Background then you must have set this key in your Plist. Add also audio permission in the plist.

Comment: Thanks but I actually have both Location and Audio set in the Plist file. 

If a audio is started while the App run then is't continue play after i minimize the App. But when this sound is done it's never start the new audio in background mode.