# Swift 2.0 Playing custom sound in app delegate while in background mode

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am using Google Cloud messaging to push notifications to my iOS app written in Swift 2.0 xCode 7.1. GCM doesn't allow custom notification sounds.
See here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

So I turned off the default sound and am trying to play a sound whenever 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' is called. My problem is the sound is not playing when in background mode..however if I put the code(below) in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' it works perfectly, just not when I want it to play.
I have added the background more in info.plist. Like I said its working just not when a push notification arrives.

```
    let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GMNotification", ofType: "wav")!)
    print(alertSound)

    //var error:NSError?
    do {
        try self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, fileTypeHint:nil)
        self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        self.audioPlayer.play()
        print("PLAY !!!")
    } catch {
        print("Error ???")
    }
```

[image]

Can anyone help please?

Comment: to play music in background mode you need to be registered as music-app in your Info-Plist-Background-modes.

Comment: Hi Christian, I have added my background modes from my info plist.

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232315/ios-play-sound-in-while-app-in-background might help you.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue. the solution should be customising the notification and then show it, but I have no idea how to do it in swift (i've succeed in android tho') .

Answer (score 0):

You must create a shared instance "Singelton" to play sound. Refer back to:

[Swift - AVAudioPlayer, sound doesn't play correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911968/swift-avaudioplayer-sound-doesnt-play-correctly)

This should tell you how it can be done